# code object is not signed at all with Ad Hoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, codesign, xcrun

I've created my very first [HelloWorld](http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-app-using-xcode-5-xib/) app and it's working great with my development provisioning profile. I can run it on my device with no problem. Now I'm trying to create an ipa file to upload it to a private appstore.

I have generated an ad hoc distribution certificate and provisioning profile with a wildcard app identifier and my iPad as device. I tried building and archiving the app both in XCode and command line. But when I want to verify my ipa file; I always get the following message:

```
codesign -d -vvvv HelloWorld.ipa
HelloWorld.ipa: code object is not signed at all
```

Here are the commands I use to generate the ipa file:

```
xcodebuild -project HelloWorld/HelloWorld.xcodeproj -configuration Release

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app -o "/Distribution/HelloWorld.ipa" --sign "iPhone Distribution: Trasys SA" --embed TrasysIOSDistributionPrvisioningProfile.mobileprovision
```

Here is the output:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app -o "/Users/admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.ipa" --sign "iPhone Distribution: Trasys SA" --embed TrasysIOSDistributionPrvisioningProfile.mobileprovision

Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/admin
SDKROOT = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
__CHECKFIX1436934 = 1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-avJlGv/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /tmp/launch-UDPqD9/Render
PWD = /Users/Admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld
USER = admin
LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
LOGNAME = admin
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0:0
SECURITYSESSIONID = 186a5
TERM_PROGRAM = Apple_Terminal
SHLVL = 1
OLDPWD = /Users/Admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld/HelloWorld
_ = /usr/bin/xcrun
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = 326
TERM_SESSION_ID = F977D8DF-A1F5-4139-A871-C4CF876F8150
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
SHELL = /bin/bash
TMPDIR = /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/
TERM = xterm-256color
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.16

Output directory: '/Users/admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app: valid on disk
HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
]
Done checking the original app
### Embedding 'TrasysIOSDistributionPrvisioningProfile.mobileprovision'
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
+ /bin/cp -rp TrasysIOSDistributionPrvisioningProfile.mobileprovision /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/entitlements_rawT841trHA /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [Executable=/private/var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
]
+ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Set :get-task-allow NO /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/entitlements_plist89xour2X
Program /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/plutil -lint /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/entitlements_plist89xour2X
Program /usr/bin/plutil returned 0 : [/var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/entitlements_plist89xour2X: OK
]
### Codesigning 'TrasysIOSDistributionPrvisioningProfile.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Distribution: Trasys SA'
+ /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Distribution: Trasys SA --resource-rules=/var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/entitlements_plist89xour2X /var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/var/folders/0r/g0g4cm0j1l5971tlj7hpk0sw0000gn/T/gh1ZWUgA0W/Payload/HelloWorld.app: replacing existing signature
]
+ /usr/bin/zip --symlinks --verbose --recurse-paths /Users/admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.ipa .
Program /usr/bin/zip returned 0 : [  adding: Payload/   (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/   (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/_CodeSignature/    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources   (in=1974) (out=563) (deflated 71%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/Assets.car     (in=75320) (out=7983) (deflated 89%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/embedded.mobileprovision   (in=7488) (out=5025) (deflated 33%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/en.lproj/  (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings (in=42) (out=23) (deflated 45%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld     (in=212960) (out=25042) (deflated 88%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorldViewController.nib   (in=2132) (out=1319) (deflated 38%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/Info.plist (in=1126) (out=738) (deflated 34%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/PkgInfo    (in=8) (out=8) (stored 0%)
  adding: Payload/HelloWorld.app/ResourceRules.plist    (in=150) (out=111) (deflated 26%)
total bytes=301200, compressed=40812 -> 86% savings
]
Results at '/Users/admin/Documents/Hans Van Beneden/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/build/Release-iphoneos/HelloWorld.ipa'
```

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Comment: you can not use wild card app id for ad hoc profile. you must be assign any explicit app id for it.

Comment: OK, I have created a new app id which matches my bundle identifier and used this to regenerate my provisioning profile. But when I retry I get the same result.

Comment: do you use distribution certificate in code signing...?

Comment: Yes, both my certificate and my provisioning profile are type Distribution and have status Active if I open them on the developer site.

Comment: Nope, never found the exact problem.